# how to handle database tables with similar fields

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

i have database tables **Applicants**, **Batteries**,**Inverters** and **Solar Panels**. the table fields on **Batteries**,**Inverters** and **Solar Panels** are the same, 

Total number

Capacity

Voltage

 and they are related to the **Applicants** table.
So my questions is should i seperate **Batteries**,**Inverters** and **Solar Panels** into individual tables or use one table and add a field to differentiate them like this 

Type (battery,inverter,solar panel)

Total number

Capacity

Voltage

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <table style="width:100%">
    <caption>Separate Databse Table</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Battery</th>
      <th>Inverter</th>
      <th>Solar Panel</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Number</td>
      <td>Total Number</td>
      <td>Total Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Capacity</td>
      <td>Capacity</td>
      <td>Capacity</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voltage</td>
      <td>Voltage</td>
      <td>Voltage</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>

  <table style="width:100%">
    <caption>Single Databse table</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Total Number</th>
      <th>Capacity</th>
      <th>Voltage</th>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As a general rule, if things' attrbutes are identical, expected to remain identical, and there is no other compelling reason to separate them, then you are probably better off with having them in the same table. .... though this does walk the line on being "opinion based".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You should use a single table to differentiate the fields as you have mentioned.

Type (battery,inverter,solar panel)
Total number
Capacity

- Type (battery,inverter,solar panel)
- Total number
- Capacity
- Voltage

You can add the foreign key of the applicants table in it for their relation as.

- **applicants_foregn_key / applicant_id**
- **Type (battery,inverter,solar panel)**
- **Total number**
- **Capacity**
- **Voltage**

Comment: I'd discourage bothering with MySQL enum type; it means an ALTER table (and hence complete table rebuild) is required just to add a new type; instead a separate `component_types` table for the actual type names, and a component_type_id in the main "components" table that references it, minimizes string comparisons and repetitions while still giving flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

It is opinion based, but there are things which can help you decide,

- What is your client program language? Is it an OO language?
- Can you consider having an object type generalizing all of those objects (Batteries,Inverters and Solar Panels)? If that's the case do the generalizing.

If your answer to these questions is positive, thing of creating a parent object for your objects and map that to a single table. If that generalization exists, it can be predicted that there will be more relationships between new objects and all of the three, so a single table solution eases the database design and database understanding.